Laplace Transform Differential equations
Given Equation is $(D^4-a^4)y = x^4$
Solving the auxiliary equation gives $D = a,-a,+ai,-ai$
So the homogeneous solution is
$y_h = c_1e^{ax} + {c_2e^{-ax}} + c_3sin(ax) + c_4 cos (ax) $
Taking the Laplace transform
$ Y(s) = \frac{24}{s^5(s^4-a^4)}$
Using the incomplete partial fraction method is a lengthy process as $s^5$ is in the denominator.
Finding the particular integral using inverse differential operator seems to be the easier method.
Is there a quicker way to solve this equation using the Laplace transform method??
If we use convolution, since we already know the homogeneous solution, does that help us in some way??

Using $\frac{1}{s^5 , (s^4 - a^4)} = \frac{1}{2 \cdot , 4! , a^3} , \frac{4!}{s^5} , \left( \frac{a}{s^2 - a^2} - \frac{a}{s^2+a^2} \right) \doteqdot \frac{1}{2 \cdot , 4! , a^3} , \int_{0}^{t} (t-x)^4 , (\sinh(ax) - \sin(ax) ) , dx $ then what is desired can be obtained. Notice that this is the convolution result of the inverse transform.

Since the right hand side of the equation is $x^4$, a polynomial. So a particular solution $y_p$ is a polynomial with degree 4.

Note that the right hand side of the equation is $x^4$, a polynomial with degree $4$. So a particular solution $y_p$ is a polynomial with degree $4$. Let
$$ y_p=a_4x^4+a_3x^3+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0 $$
be a particular solution. Then putting it in the equation gives
$$ 4!a_4-a^4(a_4x^4+a_3x^3+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0)=x^4$$
Comparing the coefficients gives
$$-a^4a_4=1,a_3=a_2=a_1=0,4!a_4-a^4a_0=0 $$
from which one has
$$ a_0=-\frac{24}{a^8},a_1=a_2=a_3=0, a_4=-\frac1{a^4}.$$
So
$$ y_p=-\frac{x^4}{a^4}-\frac{24}{a^8}. $$
Thus the general solution of the DE is
$$ y=y_h+y_p=c_1e^{ax} + {c_2e^{-ax}} + c_3\sin(ax) + c_4 \cos (ax)-\frac1{a^4}x^4-\frac{24}{a^8}.$$
Comment:

If you use Laplace transform to solve this DE, it will take longer time.

You can use the differential operator $D$ to get $y_p$. In fact
$$ y_p=\frac{1}{D^4-a^4}x^4=-\frac1{a^4}\frac1{1-(\frac{D}{a})^4}x^4=-\frac1{a^4}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\bigg(\frac{D}{a}\bigg)^nx^4=-\frac1{a^4}\bigg(x^4+\frac{24}{a^4}\bigg)=-\frac{x^4}{a^4}-\frac{24}{a^8}.$$



The book I studied from uses the inverse differential operator and states $y_p=-\frac{(x^4+(24/a^4))}{a^4}$ I'm familiar with your method(method of undetermined coefficients), however I'm inexperienced with the Laplace transform hence why I asked the question.

@HarshitBujarBaruah, you also can use differential operator to get a particular solution. See the update.

Thanks for answering
